# Scrollview not displaying all elements of a Relative Layout

Tags: android, xml, scrollview

Hi guys I'm very new to the android world and I've been having a problem with a ScrollView in my android application. The problem occurs when I change the orientation of the screen from portrait to landscape and the Sign in button is not displayed. It could be the due to the sign up button being displayed at the end of the layout. Any help would be appreciated.

The login_layout.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:layout_weight="1">

<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#ff2b8bff">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sign in"
        android:id="@+id/signInButton"
        android:background="#fffffbfd"
        android:onClick="signIn"
        android:layout_below="@+id/usersPassword"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/usersEmail"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bourguestLogo"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/usersPassword"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/usersEmail"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/usersEmail" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sign up"
        android:id="@+id/signUpButton"
        android:onClick="changeLayout"
        android:background="#ffff2f14"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bourguestLogo"
        android:src="@drawable/waiter"
        android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Is the button displayed if you only use RelativeLayout without the parent ScrollView?

Comment: "sign up" button is not visible even if you scroll the view?

Comment: No when their isn't a ScrollView the password field along with the sign in button are missing.

Comment: "sign up" button is displayed fine.The "sign in" button will not appear in landscape mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hided because *margin top* > screen height

- You set the logo on top of your view (with 88dp as margin top)
- below the logo there is UserEmail (with 31dp as margin top)
- below the UserEmail there is UsersPassword ( with 35 dp as margin top)
- and below the UserPassword we find SingIn button ( with 52 dp as margin top)

=> 88+31+35+52 dp > your screen height (on landscape mode), so your button will be hided by the *SingUpButton* (setted on the bottom of the layout  `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`)

As a solution, try my suggestion below otherwise you should decrease the top margins

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ff2b8bff">

    <ScrollView
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#ff2b8bff">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sign in"
                android:id="@+id/signInButton"
                android:background="#fffffbfd"
                android:onClick="signIn"
                android:layout_below="@+id/usersPassword"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="52dp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/usersEmail"
                android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/bourguestLogo"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/usersPassword"
                android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/usersEmail"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/usersEmail" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/bourguestLogo"
                android:src="@drawable/waiter"
                android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sign up"
        android:id="@+id/signUpButton"
        android:onClick="changeLayout"
        android:background="#ffff2f14"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```